# can we send some data with other server url in controller magento 2 like below shown

Tags: magento2, controllers

> Actually i am trying like this,Please check below code

```
  $this->_eventManager->dispatch('server url', ['FirstName' => $firstname,'LastName' => $lastname,'Postcode' => $Postcode,'EMailLogin' => $email]);
```

Comment: As you mentioned above code `server url` you want to pass `server url`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes @hitesh you can send

as per

> \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface

definition we can send array

```
public function dispatch($eventName, array $data = []);
```

you have to pass eventname instead of server url

Comment: but i have  to send some data after success action with one api url.is there anyway to do it